# Redirect web pages from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I need to re-direct 3 pages in a website from http to https. I need all other pages to remain http.

I've been scouring this site and the web for two days looking for a solution that works. Nothing has provided a complete solution.

Two pages that need https are in the root directory and one is in a subfolder. I've been fiddling with both .htaccess files, but I'm hoping everything can be done in the root file.

I'm new to regular expressions and .htaccess directives, so I apologize if the solution is obvious to some of you.

Here's the root .htaccess file I've put together so far. I'm open to your feedback on any part of the code. Thanks for your help!

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirects non-www page requests to www version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# PERTINENT CODE BLOCK BELOW

# page (order-form) has to be on https **[SEEMS TO WORK]**
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/order-form/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# page (employment-application) has to be on https  **[SEEMS TO WORK]**
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/employment-application/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# page (about/contact-us) has to be on https **[NOT WORKING]**
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about/contact-us/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# All other pages have to be on http **[NOT WORKING]**
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/order-form/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/employment-application/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about/contact-us/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# END - PERTINENT CODE BLOCK

# remove .php file extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

# adds a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# disables directory view on web pages
Options -Indexes

# cached pages will expire in 5 days
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 days"

# send 404 errors to home page
# info at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep this .htaccess in `DocumentRoot`:

```
# cached pages will expire in 5 days
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 days"

# send 404 errors to home page
# info at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument
ErrorDocument 404 /

Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# redirects non-www page requests to www version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# adds a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# 3 pages to be on https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(order-form|employment-application|about/contact-us)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# All other pages have to be on http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(order-form|employment-application|about/contact-us)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# remove .php file extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Anubhava - Thanks for taking the time. I copied your code, only changing "my website" with the actual domain. Now I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error. Any ideas?

I noticed you escaped the website extensions in RewriteCond line, but not RewriteRule line. Should they be escaped in all instances?

Comment: Ah there was a typo. Fixed it now. Try again copy/paste

Comment: The server error is gone. The two root directory files are resolving nicely to https. However, still two problems: (1) The subfolder file doesn't resolve to https. It just stays on http. And (2), I had to remove the block of code instructing "# All other pages to be on http", because it appends .php to all files and generally messes up the whole site. If you have any more ideas please let me know. I'm very grateful for your assistance.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess in `/about/` folder or is there `/about.php` file?

Comment: Good point. There is an .htaccess file in the about folder. I have .htaccess files in all sub directories.

Comment: Not in comments, edit your question and place it there.

Comment: The .htaccess file in all subfolders is essentially the same one I had in the root folder. They are meant to remove the .php extension, add a trailing slash, re-direct 404 pages to home, add the www, etc. Let me ask you please, do you think I can remove all those? Will the file we put in the root folder apply to all subfolders in the site?

Comment: I was offline today. Yes remove all the .htaccess except the one in DocumentRoot and then retest in a new browser.